# How do I make the perlin-noise module for python use a seed?

Tags: python, perlin-noise

I'm trying to add infinite generation to a game I'm working on in pygame. Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise

global world, xpix, chunkSize #set globals
    chunkSize = (12, 12)
    xpix, ypix = chunkSize[0], chunkSize[1]
    world = []
    noise1 = PerlinNoise(octaves=octaves) #make noise
    
    for i in range(xpix): # make list for drawer to use
        row = []
        for j in range(ypix):
            noise_val = noise1([i / xpix + chunkCoordX * xpix, j / ypix + chunkCoordY * ypix])

            if noise_val <= .05:
                tiletoplace = tileclassdata.water
            elif noise_val <= .13:
                tiletoplace = tileclassdata.sand
            else:
                tiletoplace = tileclassdata.grass
            placed_tile = classes.tile(tiletoplace, i, j)
            row.append(placed_tile)
        world.append(row)
```

My problem is that I can't see the same chunk more twice if I go to the same coordinate because it picks a new seed every time it generates a chunk. Is there a way I can force it to use the same seed for every chunk?

I have tried finding documentation for this plugin but I am unable to so I have looked at other questions some people have asked and none of them solve my problem. I have not been able to find any kind of solution. I have also tried not use Perlin_Noise but using python's noise module which I have tried for hours but not figured out how to operate.

Comment: The third line of the README in the `perlin_noise` repo says: `noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=3.5, seed=777)`. Is that `seed` parameter what you are looking for?

Comment: I'll try to see is it is. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor `PerlinNoise` takes a parameter called `seed`:

```
PerlinNoise(octaves=3.5, seed=777)
```

cf. line 3 in the [README](https://github.com/salaxieb/perlin_noise) of the python module.